# VBA User Defined Function (UDF): return array to multiple Excel cells as array function

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I wrote a simple function that returns an 2 dimensional array of type "Date" based on two ranges provided as function arguments.

My UDF works fine, but when I enter the formula in an Excel cell by CTRL-Shift-Enter and extend the cells to the rows below, there is always only shown the first array value (the first date).

I tried to transpose the array in the function via `Worksheetfunction.Transpose(arr)` but that did kill the Excel process. Very weird.

Here is the function:

```
  Public Function EVA_Deadlines(Start_Dates As Range, _
  Due_Dates As Range) As Date()

  Dim dates() As Date, c As New Collection, r As Range, l As Long
  
  c.add min(Start_Dates.value)
  For Each r In Due_Dates
    c.add getLastDayOfMonth(r.value)
  Next
  With New clsCollectionHelper
    Set .items = c
    Set c = .removeDuplicates
  End With
  
  ReDim dates(1 To c.count, 1 To 1)
  For l = 1 To c.count
    dates(l, 1) = c(l)
  Next
  EVA_Deadlines = dates

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

There is no problem with the VBA function but with the way the array function has to be inserted into Excel.

To be shown all array values of the UDF, there have to be selected multiple Excel cells **before** the formula is inserted into the first cell by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Entering the UDF only in one cell and extending or copying the cell formula to other cells **does not work**.

Comment: That is completely true, for older Excel versions. For newer Excel versions (including 365), it also works, but it's easier to just type the formula with Enter. Excel will "spill" into as many cells as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless "min" is a function you wrote, you should use WorkSheetFunction.Min. Also, could be the error is in "getLastDayOfMonth", perhaps post that code as well so we can see what it does.
Another thing causing the error could the be formatting of the dates themselves; would be good to test them as date and after that add them to the array.
That being said, replicating your code as best i could (i took out the custom functions), i do get different values.
My advice would be to debug the result as see what values does the array get filled with.